# Term for health retreat accommodation

Tags: translation

I've been trying to google some Japanese pages for health retreats. I've tried a few different combinations, but all I seem to get are yoga class studios or beauty salons. What term best describes the kind of accommodation where you can stay and have healthy food in a beautiful and peaceful environment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most typical are 温泉, 旅館, 温泉旅館, 宿, スパ, ヘルスセンター.

Comment: クルザール? Not sure if this fits the bill.

Comment: Most words returned Onsen results. ヘルスセンター seemed to give the most fitting results, if google translate is to be trusted. Thank you.